# 64 bit popcount using bit tricks in Python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I would like to have a bit trick implementation of 64 bit popcount in Python. I tried to copy [this code](https://gist.github.com/enjoylife/4091854) as follows:

```
def popcount_test(y):
    y -= ((y >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555)
    y = (y & 0x3333333333333333) + (y >> 2 & 0x3333333333333333)
    return ((y + (y >> 4)) & 0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f) * 0x101010101010101 >> 56
```

Unfortunately it is not right. We can see this by doing popcount on the int 1234.

```
popcount_test(1234)
261

bin(1234).count('1')
5
```

What is the correct bit trick implement in Python?

Further tests can be carried out with:

```
import random
num = random.randint(0, 2**64-1)
print(popcount_test(num), bin(num).count('1'))
```

Comment: The most obvious difference from the similar C code is that integer multiplication in Python is "infinite precision", but the C code only retains the least-significant 64 bits of the product.  So, for a start, try masking the product via `&`-ing it with `0xffffffffffffffff`.

Comment: @TimPeters Right. Or `&` with `0xff` after the `>> 56` (easy to see it'll fix the shown case).

Comment: I can confirm both above fixes work (I tested the same thing as @HeapOverflow suggested but Tim Peters', one operation earlier, would do the same).

Comment: I too would shift first and then `&` with `0xff` in practice.  The answer I gave, though, was to make it as mindless as possible to mimic what the C code actually does ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the C version expects the multiply result to only produce the low-order 64 bits, but Python uses extended precision integers so you're getting the whole thing.  You can fix it by masking the result to 8 bits after shifting it:

```
def popcount_test(y):
    y -= ((y >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555)
    y = (y & 0x3333333333333333) + (y >> 2 & 0x3333333333333333)
    return (((y + (y >> 4)) & 0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f) * 0x101010101010101 >> 56) & 0xff
```

This produces the following:

```
>>> popcount_test(1234)
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the solution obvious, I'm adding it here, but the credit goes to @TimPeters and @Heap-Overflow

```py
def popcount_test(y):
    y -= ((y >> 1) & 0x5555555555555555)
    y = (y & 0x3333333333333333) + (y >> 2 & 0x3333333333333333)
    return ((((y + (y >> 4)) & 0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f) * 0x101010101010101)  >> 56) & 0xff
```

This is how Python does it in `Modules/mathmodule.c`:

```c
static unsigned long
count_set_bits(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long count = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        ++count;
        n &= n - 1; /* clear least significant bit */
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I would like to do it in fewer operations if possible. Hence the hack.

Comment: Take my comment seriously ;-)  The answer you got is 261 = 256 + 5.  It's the answer you _want_, except bit 2**8 is also set.  In the C code, the final right shift by 56 can obviously _never_ return a result larger than 255 (it's shifting the most-significant byte into the least-significant byte position).  But because your _product_ hasn't been cut to 64 bits (which C does automatically), your Python code isn't doing the same thing.